# Is there a single term for the practice of observing nature or recording nature?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

It's what naturalists do, I guess, and I'd like to be able to express it in one word, if possible. *Birdwatching* is a related term, but too specific.

If no single term exists, What might be a brief phrase on which most scientists (I'm not one) would agree?

Comment: A sample sentence is required when asking for a single word, if you please.  Any research you have done would be helpful too.

Comment: The single word terms that come to mind would all be considered a bit gauche to professionals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a scientist — a biological scientist even — but I don’t think asking for a phrase which “most scientists agree on” is realistic, as naturalists are rather a minority among contemporary biological scientists.

The Oxford Dictionary on-line gives the older term, *Natural Historian*, for [naturalist](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/naturalist), so that I feel that the following would work in a sample sentence:

> He was engaged for many years in **studying natural history**.

or simpler:

> He spent many years **observing nature**.

I don’t think you need to try to be technical (the person in question might regard himself as indulging in zoology or ornithology etc., depending on his speciality).

Related words are to be avoided. *Naturalism* is an artistic movement, and *naturism* is going around without any clothes (which may be suitable for studying aquatic life, but is not a general feature of natural historians).